# Как передать массив из php в js?

Tags: javascript, php

```
<?
function console_log( $data ){
  echo '<script>';
  echo 'console.log('. json_encode( $data ) .')';
  echo '</script>';
}


function get_saved_locations(){
    $con=mysqli_connect ("localhost", 'root', '','locations');
    if (!$con) {
        die('Not connected : ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    // update location with location_status if admin location_status.
    $sqldata = mysqli_query($con,"select lng,lat from locations ");

    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqldata)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
        echo $r;
    }
    $indexed = array_map('array_values', $rows);
    //  $array = array_filter($indexed);

    echo json_encode($indexed);
    if (!$rows) {
        return null;
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />

    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js'></script>
  </head>

  <body>


    <div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 440px; border: 1px solid #AAA;"></div>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='maps/markers.json'></script>
    <script>    


    var tempArray = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode("[[60,30], [60.01,30.01]]"); ?>);

    var map = L.map( 'map', {
      center: [57.08233,25.24116],
      minZoom: 0.5,
      zoom: 7
    })

    L.tileLayer( 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
  subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']
  }).addTo( map )

L.marker( tempArray[0] ).addTo( map ); </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

мне нужно , чтоб появлялись точки на карте , использую строчку (ниже) то всё ок , а точек очень много и все хранятся в бд и я не могу результаты работы функции get_saved_locations() передать...  помогите, пожалуйста , весь день вчера над этим сидел , всю ночь не спал.

```
    var tempArray = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode("[[60,30], [60.01,30.01]]"); ?>);
```

Comment: "я не могу результаты работы функции get_saved_locations() " а как Вы попробовали, я же все Вам вчера написал..

Comment: есть функция get_saved_locations() верно ? верно...   я хочу передать результат ее работы в   var tempArray = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode("[[60,30], [60.01,30.01]]"); ?>); верное ? верно ... я ставлю 
var tempArray = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode(get_saved_locations()); ?>);  это не помогает . он как будто не видит .

Comment: Никогда не смешивайте код, лучше вывод php засунуть в шаблон в `data-` параметр карты и считывать ее средствами js/jQuery

Comment: кажись эту проблему  я не решу никогда

Answer (score 2):

C учетом того, как у Вас устроена функция `get_saved_locations`, писать

`<?php echo json_encode(get_saved_locations()); ?>`

не правильно

`echo` это функция вывода текста

она уже используется внутри `get_saved_locations` как и `json_encode`

```js
<?

function get_saved_locations(){
    echo json_encode("[1,2,3,4,5,6]");
}

?>


<script>    

    var tempArray = JSON.parse(<?php get_saved_locations(); ?>);
    console.log(tempArray)
    
</script>
```

[php sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4bc7c5b8f89bc0ffa18e367e592557ffd0344960)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91114/discussion-on-answer-by-stranger-in-the-q-----php--js).